# Gparted or mkfs corrupting GPT backup header/table

Tags: 20.04, gparted, gpt, gdisk

------- Edit --------

This question is not about how to install Ubuntu to a USB drive (I already know how to do that). This question is about why standard utilities are corrupting GPT tables.

------- Edit 2 -------

Including output of gdisk before and after running gparted, showing corruption of GPT table

------- Edit 3 -------

See my own answer, posted below. Short story is USB drives were defective.

------- Preliminary info -------

Ubuntu 20.04

Computer is an HP Laptop 17-by1xxx model, approximately 2 years old. I have checked the BIOS setup for any mention of RAID configuration or settings, and found in the System Configuration section, under UEFI Device Configuration, an option for Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology. Selecting that gives a screen titled

Intel(R) RST 17.5.2.4317 RAID Driver

But under that it says "No disks connected to system"

There is no option I can find to completely disable this (my built in storage device on this computer is an NVMe SSD drive).

Note that I have Ubuntu installed and properly running on a partition on the NVMe drive with no problems.

------ Actual question & background -----

I just purchased several 2tb USB thumb drives. I am attempting to set one of them up as an installed copy of Ubuntu, but running into a strange problem.

First thing I did was boot to a Live USB copy of Ubuntu (20.04.4). Then I started up gparted, to clear the drives of any lingering partitions or partition tables. Gparted started normally, and detected the new USB device, showing that it had (as expected) a FAT32 partition on it. I then used the Device menu to Create Partition Table, selected GPT, and told it to proceed. It completed without error (at least without any error it told me about).

Next, I created an empty 200mb partition, without formatting it (formatting would come later, when it was designated as the EFI partition during install). Again, no reported error.

Next, I created a 128000mb partition (to use as the root partition), formatting it as EXT4. Again, no reported error.

Finally, I created a second 128000mb partition (to use as the home partition), formatting it as EXT4. This time, gparted immediately reported "The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used". This prompt came up 3 times, then the process continued. When the process completed (allegedly successfully, according to the dialog messages), I could see the list of partitions showing that the partitions were all showing correctly, with two EXT4 formatted partitions, then the GPT table message came up again. Closing that message changes the display of the second EXT4 partition to type unknown.

Exiting gparted and running gdisk, it reports that the header of the backup table is invalid, then that the main and backup tables don't match, then that one or more CRCs don't match.

At this point, I use option x to go to Expert mode, then option e to relocate the backup table to the end of the drive (just in case), then option w to write the information to the drive.

Rescanning the drive with gdisk then shows no problems. So I go back into gparted (which reports no errors on startup), find the second partition still shows as type unknown. Choosing to reformat that partition to EXT4, starts the formatting process, but yields the same errors as above.

I have also reproduced this problem on a previously running (and fully updated) copy of Ubuntu 20.04, and on a second USB thumb drive (also 2tb in capacity).

Following a lead found in another post (sorry, I don't have a link to the post to put here - this has been a several hour process with much searching), I dumped the last 50 sectors of the disk to a file (using dd to copy them). Examining the file shows nothing useful to me (in fact not very much at all). Certainly no human readable strings or anything of the like.

I don't know if this is a problem in gparted, or if the problem is in mkfs.ext4 (which is what gparted uses to format the partition), or some other tool gparted is using, or if maybe I just rolled 5 aces and have two bad USB thumb drives.

Can anyone give me ideas of what to look at, or how to proceed in terms of getting this to successfully run?

------- gdisk output -------

```
sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdf
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sdf: 4096000000 sectors, 1.9 TiB
Model: ProductCode     
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 472F2FE1-C821-4091-8529-AF88FE2EEE41
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 4095999966
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3571302333 sectors (1.7 TiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          411647   200.0 MiB   8300  
   2          411648       262555647   125.0 GiB   8300  
   3       262555648       524699647   125.0 GiB   8300  

<here I ran gparted, and attempted to format partition 3 to EXT4>

sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdf
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.5

Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Warning! Main and backup partition tables differ! Use the 'c' and 'e' options
on the recovery & transformation menu to examine the two tables.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: OK
Backup header: ERROR
Main partition table: OK
Backup partition table: ERROR

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
Disk /dev/sdf: 4096000000 sectors, 1.9 TiB
Model: ProductCode     
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 472F2FE1-C821-4091-8529-AF88FE2EEE41
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 4095999966
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3571302333 sectors (1.7 TiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          411647   200.0 MiB   8300  
   2          411648       262555647   125.0 GiB   8300  
   3       262555648       524699647   125.0 GiB   8300
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort Nmath, but I am much more interested in why gparted (or one of the other tools it is using) is corrupting my backup GPT table than I am in getting Ubuntu installed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that none of the tools accessing the USB drives were the cause of the problem. Apparently the USB drives themselves were. I ran f3probe against them, and the drives appear to be fakes - small flash drives with the controllers "adjusted" to report larger sizes.

Posting this response in case someone comes along with a similar problem, to give them an idea of where to check.

------ output of f3probe -------

first drive:

```
sudo f3probe --destructive --time-ops /dev/sdf
F3 probe 7.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Digirati Internet LTDA.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.

WARNING: Probing normally takes from a few seconds to 15 minutes, but
         it can take longer. Please be patient.

Bad news: The device `/dev/sdf' is a counterfeit of type limbo

You can "fix" this device using the following command:
f3fix --last-sec=128337072 /dev/sdf

Device geometry:
             *Usable* size: 61.20 GB (128337073 blocks)
            Announced size: 1.99 TB (4282368000 blocks)
                    Module: 2.00 TB (2^41 Bytes)
    Approximate cache size: 1.00 MB (2048 blocks), need-reset=no
       Physical block size: 512.00 Byte (2^9 Bytes)

Probe time: 8.39s
 Operation: total time / count = avg time
      Read: 409.0ms / 4390 = 93us
     Write: 7.94s / 70315 = 113us
     Reset: 0us / 1 = 0us
```

second drive:

```
sudo f3probe --destructive --time-ops /dev/sdf
F3 probe 7.2
Copyright (C) 2010 Digirati Internet LTDA.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.

WARNING: Probing normally takes from a few seconds to 15 minutes, but
         it can take longer. Please be patient.

Bad news: The device `/dev/sdf' is a counterfeit of type limbo

You can "fix" this device using the following command:
f3fix --last-sec=124991487 /dev/sdf

Device geometry:
             *Usable* size: 59.60 GB (124991488 blocks)
            Announced size: 1.99 TB (4282368000 blocks)
                    Module: 2.00 TB (2^41 Bytes)
    Approximate cache size: 3.00 MB (6144 blocks), need-reset=no
       Physical block size: 512.00 Byte (2^9 Bytes)

Probe time: 2.54s
 Operation: total time / count = avg time
      Read: 432.6ms / 16501 = 26us
     Write: 2.06s / 61658 = 33us
     Reset: 2us / 2 = 1us
```